# J2ME (Java ME): StringItem Alignment

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

In simple words, is it possible to center a StringItem or fit it to the width of the screen? I know that I may need to provide no example code, but for instance:

```
StringItem Addbutton = new StringItem("", "Add New", Item.BUTTON);
```

How to apply it on this button for example?

Answer (score 0):

Addbutton.setLayout(StringItem.LAYOUT_CENTER);

BTW the name "Addbutton" should be rather be lowercase